# How to generate gap lock deadlock in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks, mysql-5.7

I want to explicitly generate a gap lock deadlock on MySQL 5.7, to make sure my application handles deadlocks due to gap locks correctly. I am trying to follow various simple examples online that should generate this, but I simply don't get the deadlock. I want to generate the case where MySQL detects the deadlock and rolls back one of the transactions (leaving the other one to go through).

The way I am testing this is that I open two MySQL command line windows, in both windows I do `start transaction;` followed by the respective queries on both sides to try to simulate it.

A couple of examples I tried are this: 
http://thushw.blogspot.com.mt/2010/11/mysql-deadlocks-with-concurrent-inserts.html

and this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/

Did something change in 5.7 that makes it detect gap locks better and avoid them. Is there any other simple example I could follow that generates them?

Answer (score 0):

This question may be out of date. However, I still want to post my answer to help others who have the same questions.

> 1. Initial Mysql 5.7 environment by using docker:

**docker compose** file is as following:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: lzy-test-db-mysql-57
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
```

start your **mysql 5.7 docker**:

```
PS E:\docker-env\test\mysql\57> ls


    Directory: E:\docker-env\test\mysql\57


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/23/2020  10:26 AM            539 docker-compose.yml
PS E:\docker-env\test\mysql\57> docker-compose up -d
Creating network "57_default" with the default driver
Creating lzy-test-db-mysql-57 ... done
```

> 2. Connect to your mysql server. Check environment. **tx_isolation should be RR**

```
mysql> show variables like '%isolation%';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| tx_isolation  | REPEATABLE-READ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> 3. Create table

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

> 4. Prepare data

```
insert into t (name) value ('A'), ('C'), ('D');
```

> 5. Generate gap lock deadlock

```
+====================================+============================================================+
|             Session A              |                         Session B                          |
+====================================+============================================================+
| begin;                             |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | begin;                                                     |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| delete from t where name = 'C';    |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | delete from t where name = 'C';  --Blocked!                |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| insert into t (name) values ('B'); |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The reason why this deadlock occur, please refer to [How does MySQL (Innodb) perform next-key locking when deleting record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846907/how-does-mysql-innodb-perform-next-key-locking-when-deleting-record/62916344?noredirect=1#comment111487889_62916344)