# MySQL: A deadlock occurred when deleting the same row

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, innodb, database-deadlocks

Recently I encountered a deadlock when deleting records (Note that the isolation level is **REPEATABLE READ**, MySQL 5.7)

Here is the repro steps

1 Create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

2 Prepare 3 records

```
insert into t (name) value ('A'), ('C'), ('D');
```

3

```
+====================================+============================================================+
|             Session A              |                         Session B                          |
+====================================+============================================================+
| begin;                             |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | begin;                                                     |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| delete from t where name = 'C';    |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | delete from t where name = 'C';  --Blocked!                |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| insert into t (name) values ('B'); |                                                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    | ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

The result of **show engine innodb status** as below shown (LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK section)

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3631, ACTIVE 21 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 13, OS thread handle 123145439432704, query id 306 localhost root updating
delete from t where name = 'C'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3631 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 43; asc C;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3630, ACTIVE 29 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 14, OS thread handle 123145439711232, query id 307 localhost root update
insert into t (name) values ('B')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3630 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 43; asc C;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3630 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 43; asc C;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;
```

As the Innodb status shown, session B is waiting next-key lock **C**, and session A hold a record lock **C** and waiting gap lock on **C**;

---

As we all know that

> DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters

> A next-key lock is a combination of a record lock on the index record and a gap lock on the gap before the index record.

**Q1**: I guess if session B firstly got the gap lock (part of next-key), and then waiting for the record lock. Thereby, the latter insert in session A was blocked by session B (due to the gap lock), and eventually result in a dead lock. Right?

**Q2**: As the **C** is purged from an index, does the gap lock hold by session B should be ('A', 'D')? If so, why the session A is waiting the insert intension lock on range (, 'C')?

**Q3**: Why session B has `1 row lock(s)`, and session A has `4 row lock(s)`?

---

**Q4**: When change index `p_name` to a unique index, we still get the deadlock due to gap lock, it's weird. It behaves different from official [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) which states only record lock is required.

> DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters. However, **only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row**.

---

However, it is okay when using primary key `id` to execute delete (steps as below shown). Is this a bug in MySQL?

1 Prepare data

```
delete from t;
insert into t (id, name) value (1, 'A'), (3, 'C'), (5, 'D');
```

2

```
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                 Session A                 |              Session B               |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| begin;                                    |                                      |
|                                           | begin;                               |
| delete from t where id = 3;               |                                      |
|                                           | delete from t where id = 3; Blocked! |
| insert into t (id, name) values (2, 'B'); |                                      |
|                                           |                                      |
| commit;                                   |                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't know the details, but it seems that messing around in a "gap" can lead to worse locks than would seem optimal.  In this case, the "gap" is probably all of the range between "A" and "D".  Live with it.  Write your code to restart the transaction.  The second try will probably go through without a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED" part of transaction 3631, we could see:

```
RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3631 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
```

1. 3631 is waiting a record lock. The corresponding index content is {"name":"C", "id": 24}.
2. The index name is p_name in table t.
3. lock's mode is "lock_mode X"

From "WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED" part of transaction 3630, we could see:

```
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3630 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 43; asc C;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 69 page no 4 n bits 72 index p_name of table `jacky`.`t` trx id 3630 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 43; asc C;;
 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000018; asc         ;;
```

1. 3630 is waiting a record lock. The corresponding index content is {"name":"C", "id": 24}. waiting lock's mode is "lock_mode X locks gap"
2. 3630 is holding a record lock. The corresponding index content is {"name":"C", "id": 24}. Holding lock's mode is "lock_mode X locks"
3. The index name is p_name in table t.
4. This deadlock is caused by executing "insert into t (name) values ('B')"

According to your reproduce step, session A will send a `delete from t where name = 'C';` first, this will lock:

1. ('A', 'C'] and ('C', 'D'): next-key lock 'C' and gap lock before 'D';

> [DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) sets an exclusive next-key lock on every
> record the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is
> required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search
> for a unique row.

2. add a record lock for 'C' corresponding primary index id. here id value should be "26".

Then session B will start and `delete from t where name = 'C';` will be executed again. However. For session B, because session A hadn't been committed, 'C' had been locked by session A. However, if execute a delete sql, session B will try to add lock in the following sequence:

1. gap lock before 'C': Success, because innodb could add multi gap lock in the same position.
2. record lock 'C': **Blocked**, because session A have holded that lock. session B have to wait it released by session A.
3. gap lock before 'D':

At last, session A send `insert into t (name) values ('B');`. For table `t`, there are 2 indexes, which are `id` and `name`. `id` is a auto increasement primary integer key, and for name, this sql will try to add a insert intention lock. However, there have been a gap lock which is holded by session B, therefor session A have to wait session B for releasing that gap lock. Now we could see how this dead lock occur. Innodb will choose a session to rollback base on cost. Here session B will be rolled back.

For Q1, the anwser is yes.
For Q2, actually, the deleted record wouldn't be purged from an index before its session commit.
For Q3, row lock number is equal to `trx_rows_locked`, and in mysql website, its:

> [TRX_ROWS_LOCKED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-innodb-trx-table.html)
>
> The **approximate number or rows** locked by this transaction. The value
> might include delete-marked rows that are physically present but not
> visible to the transaction.

From this [article](https://developpaper.com/understanding-mysql-lock-details-based-on-updating-sql-statements/), we could know:

> 3. For non-clustered unique index filtering, due to the need to return tables, the number of filtered rows is locked as the unique index plus
>    the number of returned rows.
> 4. For non-clustered non-unique index filtering, the gap lock is involved, so more records are locked.

So, trx_rows_locked (gap lock + next-key lock + return table) is 3 after delete in session A. final trx_rows_locked value should be 3 + 1 (insert key lock) after trying to insert.

---

The following are for the new update questions:
I didn't notice delete primary key and unique secondary key before.

After some investigating, I found:

1. When deleting a `primary key`, which have been deleted and not commited yet, the new delete operation will only require `record lock` instead of next-key lock.
2. When deleting a `secondary unique key`, which have been deleted and not commited yet, the new delete operation will require `next-key lock`.

You could use `set GLOBAL innodb_status_output_locks=ON; show engine innodb status` to see the detail lock status for running trasactions.

Comment: `For session B, because of MVCC in mysql, 'C' could be seen at that moment.` ==> I think 'C' could be seen is not because of MVCC( Session B could see it because session A has not commit the delete yet.). In my opinion, MVCC works for consistent read, and for UPDATE/DELETE statements, InnoDB does a “semi-consistent” read, such that it returns the latest committed version to MySQL.

Comment: @Jacky1205 yes, you are right. UPDATE/DELETE statement will read newest commited version of data. I will update my answer.

Comment: When I change index `p_name` to unique index, I still got deadlock with the same steps. Why? The mysql doc has said

> only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row

Comment: For what in mysql doc,  "only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row", it's correct. However, in your situation, the delete operation in session B is not just "search for a unique row". It's "searching for a unique row which is marked deleted.". In this situation, mysql will add gap lock. If you change delete operation in Session A to update operation, you will found that delete operation in session B will still be blocked, however there will not be a deadlock after insert in Session A.

Comment: If you want to avoid deadlock, try to change isolation level is RC and binlog to row. Or find a workaround in your application to avoid.

Comment: I feel confused, you mean that delete from... would always add gap lock, no matter unique index is used or not?

Comment: `searching for a unique row which is marked deleted?` I guess locking record ('C' here) is enough, why also add gap lock? It seems unnecessary

Comment: And in [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) we could see `However, only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row`  appeared in both Update... and Delete....

Comment: I have tested as you said above, change delete to `update t set name = 'CC' where name = 'C';` in session A, however still got deadlock.

Comment: Sorry for letting you confuse, You could try update t set name = 'C' where name = 'C'; this will only add a record lock on 'C'. When you delete in session A first time, mysql will add IX, record lock on 'c' and coresponding primary index lock. When you delete in session B, mysql will know session A have delete this record and will session B will get IX, gap, then waiting record lock on record C.

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand the difference between set `name` to `CC` and `C`; By the way, do you know is there any official documentation, or source code to indicates that delete statement would add gap lock on unique index in some cases?

Comment: set name to cc instead of c means: 1. msyql delete record c. 2. insert into new record cc.

Comment: `When you delete in session B, mysql will know session A have delete this record and will session B will get IX, gap, then waiting record lock on record C`. Why acquire gap lock here? I guess record lock on C is enough;  There is no deadlock when use update you suggest to replace delete; Is this because the delete in session B  only lock on record, but why?  Could you explain in details?

Comment: There is no deadlock when use primary key to execute delete. It is different from using secondary unique index. Do you know the difference?

Comment: almost the same, except that secondary unique index will lock its coresponding primary index at the same time. Can you shall your reproduce steps?

Comment: I updated the issue, to add the repro steps of using primary key at the end.

Comment: I have found a statement **If such a record is delete-marked, it may then become purged, and lock_rec_inheirt_to_gap will be called to decide the fate of each lock on it:
  either it will be inherited as gap lock, or discarded.** in [Line 2382, lock0lock.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/lock/lock0lock.cc#L2382) source file. But, I am not clear the precise rule of when will be inherited as gap lock (e.g. use secondary unique key?), or discarded (use primary key)?

Answer (score 1):

For **Q4**, I finally found [a comment in MySQL 5.7 source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/row/row0sel.cc#L4866) that explain why using next-key locks, just for reference.

> In a search where at most one record in the index may match, we
> can use a LOCK_REC_NOT_GAP type record lock when locking a
> non-delete-marked matching record.

> Note that in a unique secondary index there may be different
> delete-marked versions of a record where only the primary key
> values differ: thus in a secondary index we must use next-key
> locks when locking delete-marked records

> Note above that a UNIQUE secondary index can contain many
> rows with the same key value if one of the columns is the SQL
> null. A clustered index under MySQL can never contain null
> columns because we demand that all the columns in primary key
> are non-null.

Comment: Great job! Here explain everything! `a UNIQUE secondary index can contain many rows with the same key value if one of the columns is the SQL null`